# Sublime Text 2 up/down arrow movement keybinding

Tags: key-bindings, sublimetext

when i have one line of text on sublime text 2, say I have the line "test".
if the caret is between 'e' and 's' and I press the up button, it doesn't do anything.
I would like to change that, so if there is no line above the current one, when I press up, the caret should go to the start of the line.

same with down button.
if there is no line between the current line, the caret should move to the end of the line.

that is the default textmate behavior, and I use it a lot.

can I change that on sublime text 2 with keybindings?
I know it should be something like this:

`{ "keys": ["up"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": false }, "context":

    [

{ "key": "something", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "\n" }

    ] }`

I cannot find the right context for it. I tried preceding_text not_regex_contains "\n", but preceding_text only returns the text between the start of the current line and the caret.

any ideas?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a keybind to accomplish this. Adding the following line in your `Preferences.sublime-settings` file should do the trick:

`"move_to_limit_on_up_down": true,`

The reason for the terminating comma is because these files are in json, and if you have entries after this one, you'll need to separate them by comma. For reference, here's my Preferences.sublime-settings file as an example:

```
{
    "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
    "caret_style": "phase",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
    "draw_minimap_border": true,
    "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
    "font_size": 12,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "highlight_modified_tabs": true,
    "move_to_limit_on_up_down": true,
    "overlay_scroll_bars": "enabled",
    "show_tab_close_buttons": false,
    "tab_completion": false
}
```

You can edit this file by going to `Preferences > Settings - User` in Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you'd expect in latest dev builds - http://www.sublimetext.com/dev.

Comment: No, doesn't look like build 2220 (latest as of today) fixes this, at least not in Windows.